# Turbo C++ 2D array allocation

Tags: turbo-c++

`enter code here`![I'm using Turbo c++....whenever I assign values for a 2d array and try to display them....atleast one of the rows (or all of them) of the array won't be allocated with the proper values the user has entered. I ignored this because when the program was made to run for the 2nd time, it worked fine! But now array allocation itself isnt working properly. compiler error?

PROGRAM.... i've entered 5 rows and 2 column values....

for eg.

1    2

2    5

3    6

5    8

4    7

the above are inputs...
the output should be same as well...but it shows...

1    2

2    5

4    7

4    7

4    7

p.s. I know only to work with Turbo c++...so please dont suggest Dev c++

As a newbie, I could use some help. thanks!

THE CODE IS AS FOLLOWS
     ` #include
       #include

```
   void main()
{

float **arr;


cout<<"rows : ";
 cin>>SIZE;
cout<<"col : ";
cin>>n;

arr=new float *[SIZE];
for(int Di=0;Di<n;Di++)
{
 arr[Di]=new float[n];
}


cout<<"enter...";

for(int i=0;i<(SIZE);i++)
{
 cout<<"\n";
 for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
 {
  cout<<"\t";
    cin>>arr[i][j];
 }
}



for(int ii=0;ii<SIZE;ii++)
{
 cout<<"\n";
 for(int jj=0;jj<n;jj++)
{
    cout<<"\t";
    cout<<arr[ii][jj];
 }
}

getch();
}`
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.
please add a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: A "screen shot" of your code isn't necessary (or appropriate). Please [edit] your question to include the **relevant** code as text, properly formatted. Clearly explain what it is supposed to do, and how it is not working as it should. (Images aren't available to people behind a proxy, the code can't be copied and pasted, and it's difficult to read for people using a mobile device. In addition, you don't have sufficient privileges to post images yet.)

Comment: THANK YOU both! : I've added the program now.

Answer (score 0):

The program allocates `n` rows instead of `SIZE` rows.

You want the loop

```
for (int Di = 0; Di < n; Di++)
```

to read

```
for (int Di = 0; Di < SIZE; Di++)
```